# What are the differences between Civilization V and Civilization V: Game of the Year Edition?

Tags: civilization-5

I am looking to purchase *Civilization V*, and I see two different versions on Steam:

- *Civilization V*
- *Civilization V Game of the Year Edition*

What are the differences between them?  Does the *Game of the Year* edition include an expansion pack or DLC?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The differences are listed on the [GOTY edition's store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/901772/):

> **Includes the Following Civilization V content**
>
> - All 4 Cradle of Civilization Map Packs (Mediterranean, Asia, Americas, Mesopotamia)
> - Civilization Pack: Babylon (Nebuchadnezzar II)
> - Double Civilization and Scenario Pack: Spain and Inca
> - Civilization and Scenario Pack: Polynesia
> - Civilization and Scenario Pack: Denmark - The Vikings
> - Explorer’s Map Pack
> - Official Digital Soundtrack (Soundtrack not available on the Mac)

Comment: None taken, I am new to steam.  Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Oh now I see it.  I was looking under only Civ V  (not the GOTY) and it just showed both of them with the prices.  No explanations on the differences.

Answer (score 6):

According to [the game page of the Steam Store](http://store.steampowered.com/app/901772/) it includes the game plus the following DLC:

> - All 4 Cradle of Civilization Map Packs (Mediterranean, Asia, Americas, Mesopotamia)
> - Civilization Pack: Babylon (Nebuchadnezzar II)
> - Double Civilization and Scenario Pack: Spain and Inca
> - Civilization and Scenario Pack: Polynesia
> - Civilization and Scenario Pack: Denmark - The Vikings
> - Explorer’s Map Pack
> - Official Digital Soundtrack

That does *not* include all the released DLCs, though; you can see a complete list of them under [the Steam Store page for the regular edition](http://store.steampowered.com/app/8930/).