# What are the differences between Civilization 5: GOTY Edition and the Complete Edition?

Tags: civilization-5

Would someone please list the differences between Civilization 5: GOTY Edition and Civilization 5: Complete Edition. Also, please tell me which of the two has more content if possible. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, Civilization 5: Complete Edition contains more content.

Below is the contents of the packs, with differences marked **in bold**.

Civilization 5: GOTY Edition does not appear to be available anymore, but per [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62976/119471) by [lunboks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/9752/lunboks)

> **Includes the Following Civilization V content**
>
> - All 4 Cradle of Civilization Map Packs (Mediterranean, Asia, Americas, Mesopotamia)
> - Civilization Pack: Babylon (Nebuchadnezzar II)
> - Double Civilization and Scenario Pack: Spain and Inca
> - Civilization and Scenario Pack: Polynesia
> - Civilization and Scenario Pack: Denmark - The Vikings
> - Explorer’s Map Pack
> - **Official Digital Soundtrack (Soundtrack not available on the Mac)**

[Civilization 5: Complete Edition](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/36075/) as available on Steam, contains:

> - **Civilization V: Gods & Kings**
> - **Civilization V: Brave New World**
> - Civilization Pack: Babylon (Nebuchadnezzar II)
> - Civilization and Scenario Pack: Denmark - The Vikings
> - Double Civilization and Scenario Pack: Spain and Inca
> - All 4 Cradle of Civilization Map Packs (Mediterranean, Asia, Americas, Mesopotamia)
> - Civilization and Scenario Pack: Polynesia
> - **Civilization and Scenario Pack: Korea**
> - **Wonders of the Ancient World Scenario Pack**
> - **Scrambled Continents Map Pack**
> - **Scrambled Nations Map Pack**
> - Explorer’s Map Pack

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I can still find places where I can buy GOTY Edition but the Complete Edition always seem out of stock.